# How to fix potential buffer overrun. (Warning C6385) along with potential reading of more than 1 byte (Warning C6385)

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project that has to read ppm files and then perform some kind of manipulation to the image. When working with some photos it works fine, but in some cases, I get some annoying issues of repeating rows of pixels and overall image corruption.
In the function that reads the raw data from the file, I am getting the warnings C6385 and C6386 in regards to some potential reading of more bytes or a potential buffer overrun.

I've looked through this code a lot of times and I've tried to put some conditions that check if there is an actual overrun when working with the problematic file but I can't find any evidence that such read/write overruns happen.
I'm probably missing something, but I really can't find the problem in my logic.

```cpp
void Image::read_image(std::string fileName)
{
    std::cout << "Reading file..." << std::endl;
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::ate | std::ios::binary);

    std::streampos size = file.tellg();
    std::cout << size <<" File size" <<std::endl;
    char* memBlock;

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        size = file.tellg();
        memBlock = new char[size];
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        file.read(memBlock, size);

        int spaces = 0;
        std::streampos headerLength = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (spaces < 4)
            {
                if (memBlock[i] == '\n')
                {
                    spaces++;
                }
                headerLength += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << headerLength << " Header length." << std::endl;
        unsigned long memSize = strlen(memBlock); 
unsigned long imageLen = static_cast<unsigned long>(memSize) - headerLength;
unsigned long modifier = (static_cast<unsigned long>(memSize) - imageLen);
        unsigned long imageSize = imageLen + modifier;

        image_data.reserve(memSize);
        raw_data = new char[imageSize];

        unsigned long rawDataIndex = 0;
        for (unsigned long i = headerLength; i < imageSize - 3; i += 3)
        {
/* I get the C6385 warning on this line */ unsigned char R = memBlock[i];
                unsigned char G = memBlock[i + 1];
                unsigned char B = memBlock[i + 2];


                if (rawDataIndex < imageSize - 3)
                {               
                    raw_data[rawDataIndex] = R;
/*I get the C6386 warning on this line */ raw_data[rawDataIndex + 1] = G;
                    raw_data[rawDataIndex + 2] = B;
                }


                red_count.at(R) += 1;
                blue_count.at(B) += 1;
                green_count.at(G) += 1;
                if (R != B && B != G && R != G) { isGrayscale = false; }

                int avrg = (R + G + B) / 3;
                if (avrg != 1 && avrg != 255 && avrg != 253)
                {
                    isMonochrome = false;
                }

                Pixel pixel(R, G, B, avrg);
                image_data.push_back(pixel);
                rawDataIndex += 3;      
        }
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "*but in some cases*", do you mean you have an image which deterministically fails or that it fails sometimes with any image?

Comment: @Acorn There are images that it fails on 100% of the time and images that it works on 100% of the time. And I can't find a pattern that causes it to fail. (At first, I thought it could be the image size, but images from small to large fail, and at the same time images from small and large don't)

Comment: There is a function for writing the file, It might be a good idea for me to add it.

Comment: @Nik `unsigned long memSize = strlen(memBlock);` -- This is not correct -- don't use `strlen`.  This will stop at the first null byte, and there is no guarantee there is one in `memBlock`.  As a matter of fact, don't use any C-style string functions that rely on null termination on data that is supposedly binary in nature (like images).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie is there a way to determine how many bytes there are in my array then?

Comment: What array?  You don't have one.  You have `new[]`, which returns a pointer.  Unless you use containers such as `std::vector`, there is no way to know the amount of data you've allocated in a portable way, unless you want to drag around size variables all over the place.  I would suggest to use `std::vector<char>` anyway, instead of `new[]`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh, ok, I'll go ahead and change that, I hadn't thought about that, thanks!

Comment: Yes use `std::vector` for several reasons.   Your code currently seems to leak memory also which vector takes care of automatically.  For `vector`, using the `vector::data()` function return the pointer to the internal buffer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If I do use vector, how can I write it to a file using the file.write() function?

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, use the `data()` member function to get a pointer to the vector's data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie To read the file I use the data() member function along with file.read(), however, it doesn't seem to put anything into the vector. I do reserve a size that is as big as the file.

Comment: `std::vector<char> memBlock(size);` -- Did you do that first, or did you (erroneously) use an empty vector?

Comment: More like 
```c++
std::vector<char> memBlock;
memBlock.reserve(size);
```

Comment: @Nik That's not correct.  `reserve` does not size the vector.  If you had run your code under Visual C++ debug runtime, you would have been greeted with an `assert` dialog, and your program would stop working.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie aha, got it, anyway other than that everything seems to be working perfectly now. Thank you very much for your help I really appreciate it!